# Specified custom URL scheme is (null) but Info.plist do not contain such scheme in CFBundleURLTypes key

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have implemented firebase dynamic link in Xcode and getting below diagnostic message from Firebase:

> --- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output start ---- Firebase Dynamic Links framework version 2.3.2 System information: OS iOS, OS
> version 14.2, model iPhone Current date 2021-08-10 11:41:05 +0000
> Device locale en-US (raw en_US), timezone Asia/Kolkata WARNING: iOS
> Simulator does not support Universal Links. Firebase Dynamic Links SDK
> functionality will be limited. Some FDL features may be missing or
> will not work correctly. ERROR: Specified custom URL scheme is (null)
> but Info.plist do not contain such scheme in CFBundleURLTypes key.
> performDiagnostic detected 1 ERRORS.
> ---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output end ----

Answer (score 0):

iOS Simulator does not support Universal Links.
Try on real device.

Comment: Thanks @Sargis...On device also I am getting this can u help me - ERROR: Specified custom URL scheme is (null) but Info.plist do not contain such scheme in CFBundleURLTypes key.

I have added into the Info.plist.

Comment: @SudarshanThorve The error is saying that your dynamic link has a specified URL scheme of (null), which probably means there's a problem with the link itself.

Comment: I am also experiencing this exact same error message (with the (null)). What could be the problem with the link? The thing is that it works on Android and it also works if I use the React Native Linking component like this: Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleDynamicLink);